# How can I split my data into chunks of 7 days each

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I want to group every 7 days together. The problem is the first date is on Wednesday and I want my weeks to start on Monday and end on Sunday without dropping any data. Even the last date on my data is on Monday. This is how my data looks now:

```
date    bike_numbers
0   2017-06-28  632
1   2017-06-29  1019
2   2017-06-30  1038
3   2017-07-01  475
4   2017-07-02  523
... ... ...
550 2018-12-30  2653
551 2018-12-31  3044
```

I want it to show the bike rides only, where rows are an array of 7. I want it to look like this:

```
[632, 1019, 1038, 475, 523, 600, 558][1103, 1277,1126, 956, 433, 1347, 1506]... and so on till the last date
```

Comment: Hi Huda, will be great if you can take a look [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and  [how to make good reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
s = df.groupby(df.index // 7)['bike_numbers'].agg(list)
print (s)
0     [632, 1019, 1038, 475, 523]
78                   [2653, 3044]
Name: bike_numbers, dtype: object

print (s.tolist())
[[632, 1019, 1038, 475, 523], [2653, 3044]]
```